# How to make an Authentification using SQL Server 2005, ASP.NET MVC and EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

I have an interface for the LOG ON (connection) but it is not related to my base where I have a `USER` table (contain Login + password).

I am trying to change the LogON function in the `AccountController` like this :

```
private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string Matricule, string passWord, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ValidateLogOn(Matricule, passWord))
            {
                //return View();
                Connection(Matricule, passWord);
            }

            FormsAuth.SignIn(Matricule, rememberMe);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public int Connection(string Matricule, string passWord)
        {

            users = db.Users.ToList();
            foreach (User u in users)
            {
                if ((u.Matricule == Matricule) && (u.passWord == passWord))
                {
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any problem with this code?

There is an error which i can't fix it

> The name 'users' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you are missing a private field or local variable for users

Comment: change users = db.Users.ToList(); to var users = db.Users.ToList();

Comment: thank you guys ! the error disappear now, but I have problem in the Return of the function. 
Infact as you see, the function have to return an int .However , i return a View. I don't know how to fix coz i want to return the view of page if the LogOn suucess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared `users` yet, so you need to put a type in front of it:

```
List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
```

Also, your `Connection` function return type is `int`, but you're trying to return `View`? You should change the return type to be an `ActionResult`. Plus, you'll only ever go through that loop's first iteration as you're returning straight out of it? You'll also need a catch all if there's no users in that list.

Try this:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string Matricule, string passWord, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ValidateLogOn(Matricule, passWord))
    {
        return Connection(Matricule, passWord, returnUrl);
    }

    FormsAuth.SignIn(Matricule, rememberMe);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

public ActionResult Connection(string Matricule, string passWord, string returnUrl)
{
    List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
    ActionResult output = null;

    if (users.Any())
    {
        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            if ((u.Matricule == Matricule) && (u.passWord == passWord))
            {
                output = View();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        output = Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! but there is an error of :
The name 'returnUrl' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @anouar Ah sorry, check my edit. I'd forgot to add `returnUrl` as a parameter to `Connection`. I've also passed it in.